# adding a timstamp function and displaying on website/webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, timestamp

Thanks for stopping by. I need a help with my website on which I am working. The idea of the website is to fetch data from an XML file and display in the form of a table on the web page  using Ajax function(s). I have added various rows in that table, But I want one more row for time when the particular attribute in the XML  was changed and want it to be displayed as another table data in that row. If this possible, I would appreciate a help. Following is the code of my ajax script..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var CheckImage = "<img src='images/check.png' height='25' width='25'>";
    var CrossImage = "<img src='images/cross.png' height='25' width='25'>";
    var Fail = "<img src='images/fail.png' height='25' width='30'>";
    setInterval(url, 100);
    setInterval(redirects, 100);

    function url()
    {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/XMLFile.xml",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (xml)
                {
                    var tableContent1 = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>" +
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<th>SiteName</th>" +
                        "<th>URLType</th>" +
                        "<th>DNSStatus</th>" +
                        "<th>TargetStatus</th>" +
                        "<th>TTL</th>" +
                        "<th>SSL</th>" +
                        "<th>Force</th>" +
                        "<th>Time Changed</th>" +
                        "</tr>";
                    $(xml).find('ProdURL').each(function ()
                    {
                        tableContent1 += "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('ProdHost') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('URLType') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + ($(this).attr('DNSStatus') == "OK" ? CheckImage : CrossImage) + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + ($(this).attr('TargetStatus') == "OK" ? CheckImage : CrossImage) + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('TTL') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + ($(this).attr('SSL') == "OK" ? CheckImage : CrossImage) + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('Force') + "</td>" +

                            "</tr>";
                    });    
                    tableContent1 += "</table>";
                    $("#UpdatePanel").html(tableContent1)
                    getdata(tableContent1);


                }


            });

    }

 });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I#M not allowed to comment a question... But it's not clear to me, what is your exact question, what's wrong, what happens and what did you expect to happen?

What I can see: You have 8 tableheaders () but only 7 columns () in your code.

Comment: The reason you are only looking at those empty tables because you don't have XML from which the data is being parsed.. I want a time stamp to be displayed, when I change the data in the XML

Comment: So where is your XML-File located? In the same directory as your JavaScript? Then change  url: "/XMLFile.xml" to  url: "XMLFile.xml". And keep in mind that the filename is case senstitive.